# Transmute nested const generic array (Rust)

Tags: arrays, rust, const-generics

I want to do

```
pub fn col_vec<T:Sized, const DIM0: usize>(mat: [T; DIM0]) -> [[T; 1]; DIM0] {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(mat) }
}
```

which is obviously safe to do. Rust rejects it as

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> vf\src\shape_arr.rs:22:14
   |
22 |     unsafe { std::mem::transmute(mat) }
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `[T; DIM0]` (this type does not have a fixed size)
   = note: target type: `[[T; 1]; DIM0]` (this type does not have a fixed size)
```

Is there some way around this?

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer, if you really wanted to transmute, you could do it with `transmute_copy()`, as `transmute()` is currently too strict ([issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956)) regarding types whose size depends on a const generic. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f2ae364d5ecc3ab197dbbe043302b104)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
pub fn col_vec<T, const DIM0: usize>(mat: [T; DIM0]) -> [[T; 1]; DIM0] {
    mat.map(|x| [x])
}
```

The above code does the same thing using safe operations. While [`array::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map) does sometimes result in code generation, in this case, the compiler appears capable of optimizing it down to just a copy of the entire array (and, presumably, nothing at all within some larger algorithm). I would recommend using this option.

---

Another option which is closer to `transmute()` is:

```rust
pub fn col_vec<T: bytemuck::Pod, const DIM0: usize>(mat: [T; DIM0]) -> [[T; 1]; DIM0] {
    bytemuck::cast(mat)
}
```

This version uses [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/), a library for performing byte-reinterpreting conversions between arbitrary types as long as it is safe to do so (which the `T: bytemuck::Pod` bound ensures). This is very flexible and can do any kind of matrix reshaping, but it has the disadvantage that the element type must meet the `Pod` constraint (it must not contain any pointers or padding, for example). This requirement is because, for individual conversions, `bytemuck` *only* checks that the input and output have the same *length*, so it can be used to do things like turning `[u32; 4]` into `[u16; 8]` or similar reshaping at the byte level.